# Clear Radio Button's When Containing Row Is Hidden

Tags: angularjs

I have a angujarJS application and I have a form with hidden rows.  when 'Yes' is selected to the trigger row, another row is displayed with a 'Yes' and 'No' radio button on.

What I'm trying to do is clear any selected radio button for the hidden row if 'No' is selected in my trigger row but I cant figure it out at all.

Its probably easy but I'm just code blind with it.

**Trigger row**

```
<div class="row">
     <label class="col-sm-7 col-md-6">Show hidden row?</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input name="firstgroup" type="radio" ng-model="transferitems.firstgroup" value="Yes" required />Yes &nbsp;
          <input name="firstgroup" type="radio" ng-model="transferitems.firstgroup" value="No" required />No &nbsp;
     </div>
</div>
```

**Hidden row**

```
<div class="row" ng-show="transferitems.firstgroup == 'Yes'">
     <label class="col-sm-7 col-md-6">Is hidden row displayed?</label>
     <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input name="secondgroup" type="radio" ng-model="transferitems.secondgroup" value="Yes" required />Yes &nbsp;
          <input name="secondgroup" type="radio" ng-model="transferitems.secondgroup" value="No" required />No &nbsp;
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can condense Neel's answer and put the assigment directly in the ng-click expression on the 'No' element.  It is a more compact and don't have to have extra function in $scope.

Like so:

```
   <input name="firstgroup" type="radio" ng-model="transferitems.firstgroup"
         ng-click="transferitems.secondgroup=''" value="No" required />No
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `ng-click` on trigger row like

```
<input name="firstgroup" type="radio" ng-model="transferitems.firstgroup" value="No" ng-click="triggerChange()" required />
```

Then you can define a scope function where you would check the first row trigger condition and accordingly clear hidden radio buttons.

```
 $scope.triggerChange = function(){
     if($scope.transferitems.firstgroup=="No"){
          $scope.transferitems.secondgroup='';
     }
  }
```

Another way is to pass `$event` to `ng-click="triggerChange($event)"`

then you can compare value

```
 if(event.target.value == "No"){
              $scope.transferitems.secondgroup='';
 }
```